# What will be the probability that at least two shots hit?

Tags: probability

$P$ can hit a target 4 times in 5 shots, $Q$, 3 times in 4 shots and $R$, twice in 3 shots,. They fire simultaneously. What is the probability that at least $2$ shots hit?


P.S.Here the question has given probability of P,Q and R separately.How to combine them to find the overall probability,also what concepts of probability is involved in this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can calculate the probability of only one shot hit and no shot hit, then use 1 minus the the total.

P(at least 2 shots) = 1 - [ P(PQ'R') + P(P'QR') + P(P'Q'R) + P(P'Q'R') ]

Comment: oh yeah,i interpreted the question differently.Here each of them shot only once so the question is pretty easy. Thank you for the answer!